# Pinned section's scrollTrigger start position is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

i have 5 sections and each sections height is 100vh. but i need more scroll area so i pin each of the 5 sections.Then i have a scrollTrigger method which the trigger is section1 and the start is from center but it is not starting from the center of the section1 . if any one knows how to fix this please help.Please

https://codepen.io/unni-krishnan-the-vuer/pen/PoVwOvN

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger)

const section1Timeline = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section1",
    pin: true,
    start: "top top",
    scrub: true
  }
});

gsap.to(".section1>h1", {
  color: "red",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section1",
    markers: true,
    scrub: true,
    start: "center center"
  }
});

const section2Timeline = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section2",
    pin: true,
    start: "top top",
    scrub: true
  }
});

const section3Timeline = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section3",
    pin: true,
    start: "top top",
    scrub: true
  }
});

const section4Timeline = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section4",
    pin: true,
    start: "top top",
    scrub: true
  }
});

const section5Timeline = gsap.timeline({
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".section5",
    pin: true,
    start: "top top",
    scrub: true
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section1 {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.section2 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section3 {
  background: aqua;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section4 {
  background: green;
  height: 100vh;
}

.section5 {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@3/dist/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <div class='section1'>
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='section2'>
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='section3'>
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='section4'>
    <h1>Section 4</h1>
  </div>
  <div class='section5'>
    <h1>Section 5</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```